# How to output a permanently delete comment link?

Tags: php, comments

I'm trying to output a "delete comment" link on the front-end. Here's my attempt so far:

```
printf(
    '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
    wp_nonce_url(
        admin_url( "comment.php?c=$comment_id&action=deletecomment" ),
        'delete-comment_' . $comment_id
    ),
    __( 'Delete comment', 'text-domain' )
);
```

I've added `edit_comment` cap to the author role. However, when I log in as an author and click on Delete comment, I get the following message on a white screen of death:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to edit comments on this post.
>
> Thank you for creating with WordPress.
>
> Version 4.7.4

How can I output a permanently delete comment link which works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After briefly testing, the code snippet from OP seems to work:

```
printf(
    '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
    wp_nonce_url(
        admin_url( "comment.php?c=$comment_id&action=deletecomment" ),
        'delete-comment_' . $comment_id
    ),
    esc_html__( 'Delete comment', 'text-domain' )
);
```

But it looks like we have to make sure that the *author* is only **deleting comments on hir own post**, otherwise it will look for the `edit_others_posts` and `edit_published_posts` *primitive* capabilities.

The `edit_comment` is not a *primitive* capability, so instead we have to look at the [`map_meta_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/) function to see what *primitive* capabilities it relies on. There we can see that `edit_comment` is a *meta* capability that uses:

```
$caps = map_meta_cap( 'edit_post', $user_id, $post->ID );
```

for non-orphaned comments. Then we have to look at the part where the `edit_post` meta capability maps to other  *primitive* capabilities. There are few possible mappings there, e.g. to `edit_others_posts` and `edit_published_posts` *primitive* capabilities.

Jean Galea has written a great [article](https://www.wpmayor.com/roles-capabilities-wordpress/) on roles and capabilities, where it says:

- Primitive capabilities are assigned to user roles.
- Meta capabilities never should be assigned to a role.

Comment: Strange! I did try deleting own comments only. Can I ask how you're adding the `edit_comment` cap? Maybe that's what I'm doing wrong. My approach is `$role = get_role( 'author' ); $role->add_cap( 'edit_comment' );` and I'm hooking to `after_switch_theme`

Comment: I've figured out what's going on here. Using my snippet, you can delete your own comments if, and only if, that comment is associated with your **own** post. If you comment on another author's post, you can't delete the comment even with the `edit_comment` cap.

Comment: I updated the answer @henrywright

Comment: Thanks @birgire for making sense of this. `edit_post` isn't documented [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) but I guess it is a capability belonging to the post author only. Hence why the comment author can't delete their comment(s) in such cases.

Comment: you're welcome. I updated with a link to an hopefully helpful article, that I just found.

Comment: Making a note here that the `map_meta_cap` hook was the solution for me. It'll allow me to use custom mappings instead of the default mappings used by WordPress in `map_meta_cap()`.